# Mist doesn't work when looking through a glass object

Tags: rendering

I am working on a project. There is one scene that the camera is looking through a window that use the glass material to see the view outside. I decided to turn on the mist pass. Then I saw something isn't right. The mist just end at the window.
 Then I don't know what to do. This is an example.[image: Example]

Comment: The Compositing method of adding mist or fog uses depth, so it is not a "true" fog. You should try using a cube with a volumetric shader instead.